# How to disable buttons until a video ends in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-video

I have an mp4 video that I control from the component.ts file. My html template file is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary play-button" (click)="playVideo()"><i class="fa fa-play fa-2x"></i> Play the video</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary play-button" (click)="pauseVideo()"><i class="fa fa-pause fa-2x"></i> Pause the video</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-info play-button disabled"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i> Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-info play-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i> Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my component.ys file is:

```
playVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
}

pauseVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
}
```

I would like to make `next` button disabled during the video and make it enabled after the video ends. I couldn't find a good source in angular to accomplish this. I was wondering if you could share with me a tutorial, a post or a way to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated! 
PS: The video is not youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You consider spying on `onend` event to track when video ends, but as far is the button hiding part is concern, you can enable a flag as soon as video starts and end when video `onend` event triggered.

**HTML**

```
<video #videoplayer controls (ended)="videoEnd()" style="width: 1200px;">
    <source 
      src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" 
      type="video/mp4"> 
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('videoplayer') videoplayer;
  isEnded: boolean = false;
debugger
  pauseVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.pause();
  }

  playVideo(event: any) {
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
    this.isEnded = false
  }

  videoEnd(event: any) {
    this.isEnded = false;
    alert('Video Has Ended')
  }
}
```

To register `onended` event you could use either `#templateVariable` with combination of `ViewChild` or directly register `onend` on DOM using `(ended)="videoEnd($event)"` over video element.

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9gifm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I followed your approach. I even did the https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onended_video example. But nothing happened at my browser. No error, nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add plunker / stablitz here..?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EPLjXhaRYS7Sci2628Er 
Or the w3 link on my previous comment is the exactly the same one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! I could not see that for some reason:)

Comment: @GoGo what you didn't see ?

Comment: I did `isEnded: boolean = true;` instead of `false`.